# CASE Expression in T-SQL changing other column-value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I'm working with T-SQL and I want to write a `CASE` expression.
I do have a table with columns: `Username` and `Usertype`. If the `Username` is for example `'Demo'` then I want to have the `Usertype` filled with `'special'`. Else the `Usertype` should be `'normal'`.
I tried following:

```
SELECT Username, Usertype, 
    CASE Username WHEN 'Demo' THEN Usertype = 'Special' 
    END
    FROM Table1
```

maybe someone could help me as it doesn't work.

Comment: `CASE` **expression**; T-SQL does not support `Case` (`Switch`) statements.

Comment: As for the problem, a `CASE` **expression** returns a scalar value; you are trying to return a boolean result: `Usertype = 'Special'`.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Is there the possibility to manage this in another way? Maybe with an IF statement?

Comment: `IF` is a logical flow operator; it can't be used within a `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track:

```sql
SELECT Username, Usertype, 
       CASE Username WHEN 'Demo'
                     THEN 'special' ELSE 'normal' END AS UsertypeNew
FROM Table1;
```

If you actually want to *update* your table, then use:

```sql
UPDATE Table1
SET Usertype = CASE Username WHEN 'Demo' THEN 'special' ELSE 'normal' END;
```